# How to recover User ID snapshot file?

Tags: photos, apple-id

I have accidentally changed my user ID picture on my Macbook Pro (running OS X 10.7.5). The original user ID snapshot is very dear to me and I can't find the original file saved anywhere. Is there a way to reset/recover the original User ID snapshot? I have tried to find it under Library/ User Pictures/ but only the pre-installed icons seem to be showing here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command in Terminal and see what happens:

```
dscl . -read /Users/[user_shortname] JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/any_file_name.jpg
```

For example:

```
dscl . -read /Users/U92 JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/U92.jpg
```

Gleaned and distilled from this [AskDifferent page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/where-does-the-mac-store-account-pictures).

Comment: / To be honest, I don't know the next thing about using Terminal, but after reading up on it a little, I figured I should pop into an iCentre to ask a technician's advice on how to use it before I exidently ended up causing more damage. I left more confused...:) Anyway, I decided to download a data recovery software and started scanning through the files. It was a painstakingly tedious (and a very rudimentary) way to go about it, but I have finally found the lost file!