# Where is my login picture saved?

Tags: macos

Where is my login picture saved? I would like to use it for other apps but cannot find it under pictures or in any other document folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does OS X store the profile photo it takes when you first create an account?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3664/where-does-os-x-store-the-profile-photo-it-takes-when-you-first-create-an-accoun)

Comment: I think your question is a [duplicate of this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/where-does-the-mac-store-account-pictures).

Comment: I'm fine with all three of these. One triggers from login picture, one from profile picture and one from account picture. If we end up with more than 5 or 6 versions of this, perhaps it'll be time to thin it down - cross linking them is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What version of what OS are you running?

Answer (score 3):

It is encoded in a plist file at the location **/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users**

For more information on this, see another Q&A here:

- [Where does OS X store the profile photo it takes when you first create an account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3664)